# Complex sp_executesql - vulnerable to injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

Just started a new job, and I have found an insanely complex call to `sp_executesql` (SQL Server 2008 R2). I can't decide whether it is vulnerable to SQL injection or not.

The following is defined as a single C# `string` (so no additional escaping):

```
declare @temp table(keyid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name nvarchar(50));
insert into @temp (name) select distinct name from SOMEWHERE where code=@code;

declare @names nvarchar(max); 
declare @dyn nvarchar(max); 

-- dynamically build the columns
select @names = Stuff ((select '],['+name from @temp order by name for XML PATH('') ),1,2,'')+']'; 

-- dynamically build the pivot query
set @dyn = N'select '+ @names +' from (select name, score from TABLE where code='''+@code+''') as p PIVOT
    (max(score) for name in ('+ @names +')) as pivtab';

execute sp_executesql @dyn
```

And then the whole lot is executed as so

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@code nvarchar(500)',@code=N'..something..'
```

So `@code` is both used properly (in the insert statement) but also used badly in the construction of `@dyn` (and `@names` too, one of those name fields could contain malicious script).

It seems like a bad code smell, but I can't seem to write a value for `@code` that will execute arbitrary SQL. And I lack the authority to just force the issue.

Does anyone know if this type of thing is safe or not? Thanks

Comment: If dynamic pivot is insanely complex you probably don't see insanely complex queries.

Comment: But is it safe? My preference is not to use dynamic SQL like this. I would pivot it in the application layer.

Comment: @code is vunerable for one

Answer (score 2):

This looks like classic dynamic `PIVOT`.

```
declare @temp table(keyid int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name nvarchar(50));

insert into @temp (name) 
select distinct name from SOMEWHERE where code=@code;

declare @names nvarchar(max) 
       ,@dyn nvarchar(max); 

-- dynamically build the columns
select @names = Stuff ((select ','+ QUOTENAME(name) 
                        from @temp 
                        order by name 
                        for XML PATH('') ),1,1,''); 

-- dynamically build the pivot query
set @dyn = 
   N'select '+ @names +' from (select name, score from TABLE where code=@code) 
    as p PIVOT
    (max(score) for name in ('+ @names +')) as pivtab';

execute dbo.sp_executesql 
        @dyn,
        N'@code DATATYPE',
        @code;
```

I would:

1. Use [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) instead of concatenating `],[` (just as good practice)
2. Parametrize `@code` (possible vector of attack, user can pass malicious code)

If you can do `PIVOT` in application layer do it.

I recommed also to read [`The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful - I didn't think of specifying @code as a parameter of the internal query.

Comment: @jane0027 Doing it you are sure code like `blabla'; DROP TABLE ... ;--` is parametrized.

Comment: +1 . . . It is worth pointing out that with the changes suggested, the code should not be vulnerable because the names are coming from system tables and properly quoted.  The original code would be vulnerable to an attach where `@code started with a single quote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't like concatenating `[` because there are edge cases like [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396350) If you try concat version you will end up with invalid identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice. I will push for moving the pivot to C# (the dynamic query has a vast number of columns.. and they grow with time). Any useful resources for debugging dynamic SQL? All I could get out of SQLMS and Profiler was the initial call, but not the inner constructed calls.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Perhaps you misunderstood my comment.  I only meant that you should explicitly answer the question, as well as providing the additional, very useful, information.